# Dismissing custom modal view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am loading a UIImagePickerController in this way:

```
- (void) launchCamera {

// Set up the camera
CustomCamera *cameraController = [[CustomCamera alloc] init];
cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraController.delegate = self;

cameraController.showsCameraControls = NO;
cameraController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
cameraController.toolbarHidden = YES;

// overlay on top of camera lens view
UIImageView *cameraOverlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"camera_overlay.png"]];
cameraOverlayView.alpha = 0.0f;
cameraController.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlayView;

// animate the fade in after the shutter opens
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.2f];
cameraOverlayView.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];

[customCamera presentModalViewController:cameraController animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to dismiss it. When I try

```
 [cameraController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
```

The cameracontroller still is not removed from the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
[customCamera presentModalViewController:cameraController animated:YES];
```

with this

```
[self presentViewController:cameraController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and dismiss code type this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES  completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

To present a view controller modally, you should use this method:

```
 - (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

To dismiss a modal view controller, you should use this method:

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

Per the inline comment above these methods (`UIViewController.h`):

`The next two methods are replacements for presentModalViewController:animated and dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: The completion handler, if provided, will be             invoked after the presented controllers viewDidAppear: callback is invoked.`

***Here's what's wrong with your code:***

You're using the deprecated method to present your modal view controller and trying to dismiss it with the new method... this won't work.

Comment: Ok thanks for summarizing my comment into answer. Should be clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES  completion:nil];
```

happy coding...

Comment: As mentioned in my answer - check my last edit because this method is depracated.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski, this method isn't deprecated... the methods with `modal` in their signature are deprecated. Check `UIViewController.h` for proof.

Comment: @JRG-Developer problem is he is using deprecated method to show ViewController - that's the main problem and it won't work together with new methods. In code pasted in problem description you see he is using it and it's not working...

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski, Yep

Comment: So this answer is just wrong - please remove it - it's not gonna fix a problem.

Comment: I have already tried this, but since it is called from the viewcontroller.h and not from the cameraController it won't dismiss it

Answer (score -2):

If you are adding ViewController as modal - use:

```
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

inside your view controller.

Please be aware of fact the both functions with "Modal" in name were deprecated in iOS 6.0. Use presentViewController:animated:completion: instead.